# ng-click does not work after introducing https

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I implement log in and log out feature. I'm using .NET MVC and angularJS. Everything was working until I put in HTTPS.

This is my angularJS code for logout:

```
function getCareersView(myPath, myView) {
    //var path = $window.location.pathname;
    var pathParts = myPath.split('/');
    var result = '/';
    for (var i = 0; i < pathParts.length; i++) {
        if (pathParts[i] !== 'Careers' && pathParts[i] !== '') {
            result += pathParts[i];
            result += '/';
        };
        if (pathParts[i] === 'Careers') {
            result += pathParts[i];
            break;
        };
    };
    result += myView;
    return result;
};


var mainModule = angular.module('main', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap']);

mainModule.controller('mainController', function ($http, $scope, $location, $window) {
    $scope.currentUserName = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('userName');
    $scope.currentUserID = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('userID');
    $scope.currentProfileID = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('profileID');

    $scope.logOut = function () {
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('userName', null);
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('userID', null);
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('profileID', null);
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('currentJobID', null);
        $window.sessionStorage.setItem('justApplied', 'false');

        $scope.currentUserName = undefined;
        $scope.currentUserID = undefined;
        $scope.currentProfileID = undefined;
        $window.location.href = getCareersView($window.location.pathname, '/JoinBlueScope');

    };

});
```

This is my HTML code:

```
        @*<li ng-click="logOut()" ng-show="currentUserName != undefined && currentUserName !=='null'"><a href="#" id="careerLoginLogoutLink">log out</a> </li>
        <li ng-show="currentUserName == undefined || currentUserName ==='null'">@Html.ActionLink("Log in / Register", "Login", "Careers", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "careerLoginLogoutLink" })</li>*@

        <li ng-show="currentUserName != undefined && currentUserName !=='null'"><a href="#" id="careerLoginLogoutLink" ng-click="logOut()">log out</a> </li>
        <li ng-show="currentUserName == undefined || currentUserName ==='null'">@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Log in / Register", actionName: "Login", controllerName: "Careers", protocol: "https", hostName: Request.Url.Authority, fragment: null, routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "careerLoginLogoutLink" })</li>
```

The 2 li tags that are commented out is the previous code that works without HTTPS.

I decorated my CareersController with [RequiredHttps] and all other controllers with [ExitHttps].  I followed this link to implement ExitHttps attribute:

http://www.primaryobjects.com/2012/04/23/moving-in-and-out-of-ssl-https-in-c-mvc-asp-net/

I can provide this code and controllers if we need it.  When they click "log out", I just reset the session and reroute them to a secured page.  I don't have logout action in my controller.  I do have login action.

My problem is when I log out, I cannot log back in.  I have a JQuery exception complaining href property is invalid. I think I have a mixed content situation, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can you please give me some advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no jQuery code even shown in question.

Comment: I don't have jquery code.  It crashes in JQuery used by angularJS.  It's an invalid argument exception.  "href" property is not defined.

Here's the function it crashed in angularJS:

    $rootElement.on('click', function(event) {
});

and it crashed at line: var absHref = elm.prop('href');

Comment: if I remove the [RequireHttps] attribute and remove the 2 new li tags, uncomment out the old li, it will work, but I don't have HTTPS.  So I know the problem is in those 2 li tags.

Comment: Have you looked at actual href that is being sent to browser? No idea what jQuery is even being used on those links to cause error in first place. Sounds like some sort of navigation code or something

Comment: I put a break point at the last line in logout().  $window.location.href has correct value at that time.  But when it crashes, the href property is undefined.

Comment: Ooooo   I was looking at wrong links that have real href. Don't use `#` as href or if you do you need to `preventDefault()`

Comment: Also sounds like maybe your router doesn't have an `otherwise` config or any route change error handler

Comment: I've been fighting this all day.  I put in 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#careerLogoutLink").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        $("#careerLoginLink").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>

but preventDefault() never gets called.

Answer (score 0):

it turned out this only happens in IIS Express at local machine.  I published the same code to Azure and everything works.